# Some buttons don't work after suspend andresume

Tags: keyboard, suspend, hibernate, dmesg

dot (.) and functional buttons (brightness) don't work

OS: Ubuntu 21.10 x86_64
DE: GNOME 40.5
CPU: AMD Ryzen 7 5700U
GPU: AMD ATI 03:00.0 Lucienne
kernel: 5.13.0-20-generic

Similar question is here
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/198685/some-function-buttons-not-recognised-even-at-scancode-level-after-resume-from

partial output of

```
sudo dmesg | grep i8042
```

here

```
[    0.683130] i8042: PNP: PS/2 Controller [PNP030b:PS2K] at 0x60,0x64 irq 1
[    0.683898] serio: i8042 KBD port at 0x60,0x64 irq 1
[    0.692530] input: AT Translated Set 2 keyboard as /devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input2
[   19.887014] input: AT Translated Set 2 keyboard as /devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input12
[  142.744956] input: AT Translated Set 2 keyboard as /devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input13
```

and after every suspend and resume cycle it continues to add keyboards

what is nearby

```
[   19.320138] pci 0000:00:00.2: can't derive routing for PCI INT A
[   19.320146] pci 0000:00:00.2: PCI INT A: no GSI
```

and

```
[   19.887014] input: AT Translated Set 2 keyboard as /devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input12
[   19.887413] atkbd serio0: Spurious ACK on isa0060/serio0. Some program might be trying to access hardware directly.
```

A strange thing is that dot button doesn't work

`xev` doesn't react on the key press, brightness controll (fn+F4, fn+F5) too

I have tried everything from this list to configure grub

```
#i8042.nopnp noacpi nolapic atkbd.reset
#i8042.direct
#i8042.nopnp i8042.dumbkbd
#i8042.noaux=1
#i8042.reset
#i8042.kbdreset
```

Nothing helped, sometimes the keyboard stopped responding and sometimes caps-lock indicator stopped indicating

Please help me, I've spend 3 full days trying to configure the suspend mode with no result

Comment: changing xkeyboard-config to asus_laptop didn't help

Comment: blacklist asus-nb-wmi and blacklist asus-wmi didn't help

Comment: Same question https://askubuntu.com/questions/1380496/asus-vivobook-dot-key-and-brightness-fn-controls-dont-work-after-suspend