# How to hibernate after some time or when battery is discharged

Tags: suspend, power-management, battery, hibernate, schedule

I use Ubuntu 21.04. `sudo systemctl hibernate` works fine to hibernate. But suspend doesn't (see: [Some buttons don't work after suspend andresume](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1370495/some-buttons-dont-work-after-suspend-andresume/1370599))

How can I automate hibernation when using battery for these rules:

- 45 minutes inactive
- less than 10% battery left

Is it possible also to prevent sleep when I close the lid? I set logout and blank, but still get sleep

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the issue I used dconf Editor, see path `/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/power/`

I had also change `/etc/systemd/logind.conf` to ignore lid