# Asus Vivobook - Dot key and brightness Fn controls don't work after suspend

Tags: keyboard, suspend, laptop, asus

I have Ubuntu 21.10 working out of the box on an Asus Laptop (Vivobook Pro - Oled, Ryzen 5, RTX 3050), but I've noticed that "dot key" and brightness controls (<kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>-<kbd>F5</kbd>) don't work after suspend and resume.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Same problem here, I decided to use an external keyboard, it works without problem.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading to kernel `5.13.0-27` fixed this issue. Simply, run:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

Comment: Negative Running 5 13 0-35 Ubuntu Budgie dot key and brightness still missing after suspend